# How to sort barcode string in ASC in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I have one table name `self_instrument` that have one column `Id_number` i.e its barcode for instrument .. 
I want show record as per Id_number in Ascending order 
like below

```
ACA1/STD/01-->this is barcode
ACA2/STD/01
ACA3/STD/01

ACB1/STD/01
ACB2/STD/01
.
.
.
.
```

mysql query is

```
SELECT Distinct Id_number  
FROM  `self_instrument` 
WHERE `Id_number` != ''   
ORDER BY if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
            SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) +1 ) ,
            concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) , 
        if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
            SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , 1, 3 ) , 
            concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) , 
        CAST( if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
                  SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , 4, LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) -4 ) , 
                  concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) AS UNSIGNED )
```

but when i running this it shows output like

```
WT/CI-EQ/2011/500   -->these are some exceptional barcode in the records 
BLORE/DHTC/ALAB/50-600/01   --->same as above 
AC/INST/021     
AC/INST/021     
ACA1/STD/01         
ACA2/STD/01         
ACA3/STD/01     
ACA4/STD/01     
ACA5/STD/01     
ACA6/STD/01
```

So as per asc order it needs to show 
A first then in last W
and series pattern 
is like 
ACA1/STD/01
ACA2/STD/01
ACA3/STD/01

Comment: Your first `ORDER BY` criteria is the substring after the `/`. Since `CI-EQ` is lower than `STD`, it comes first.

Comment: You still haven't explained. Is it first by the first three characters, then by the last number, then by the number after the first three characters, then by everything after the first `/`?

Comment: yes, if you see the result WT,B Id_number showing on top and then A letter Id_number is showing then how can i filter this by Asc, if i change in query the Id_number pattern changes just tell me how can i show the above result like    AC/INST/021     
AC/INST/021     
ACA1/STD/01         
ACA2/STD/01         
ACA3/STD/01     
ACA4/STD/01     
ACA5/STD/01     
ACA6/STD/01 WT/CI-EQ/2011/500

Comment: Isn't that what I did in my updated answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sorting first by the substring after the `/`. I think you want that to be the last criterion:

```
SELECT Distinct Id_number  
FROM  `self_instrument` 
WHERE `Id_number` != ''   
ORDER BY 
        -- Sort first by 3-letter prefix 
        if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
            SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , 1, 3 ) , 
            concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) , 
        -- Then by number after last `/`
        CAST(IF( LOCATE ('/', Id_number ),
                SUBSTRING_INDEX( Id_number, '/', -1), 
                CONCAT( 'z', Id_number) ) AS UNSIGNED ),
        -- Then by number after the prefix
        CAST( if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
                  SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , 4, LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) -4 ) , 
                  concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) AS UNSIGNED ),
        -- Finally by everything after first `/`
        if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
            SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) +1 ) ,
            concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) )
```

Comment: Hi Barmar Sorting is right but pattern is wrong it showing pattern ACA1/STD/01 ACA1/STD/02 but i want ACA1/STD/01 ACA2/STD/01

Comment: Could you please update your question and explain the ordering criteria. It's really hard to tell just from 2 lines.

Comment: I changed by code, is it correct now? I'm still just guessing what your sort order is supposed to be, because you won't explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from     
(    
SELECT Distinct Id_number  
FROM  `self_instrument` 
WHERE `Id_number` != ''   
ORDER BY if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
            SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) +1 ) ,
            concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) , 
        if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
            SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , 1, 3 ) , 
            concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) , 
        CAST( if( LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) >0, 
                  SUBSTRING( `Id_number` , 4, LOCATE( '/', `Id_number` ) -4 ) , 
                  concat( 'z', `Id_number` ) ) AS UNSIGNED )

) tbl order by 1 asc;
```

Can you try this ? It should work.

Comment: Why do you order in the subquery, and then put it in a completely different order in the outer query?

Comment: Hi vinit sorting is right but series pattern is wrong.. I want pattern like ACA1/STD/01 ACA2/STD/01 but showing ACA1/STD/01,ACA1/STD/02